# Installing Phinx on Wamp Server

Tags: php, windows, cmd, wamp, phinx

I want to use "Phinx" in my project using wamp server.I was able to install with cmd:

Following instructions at:
http://docs.phinx.org/en/latest/install.html

```
composer require robmorgan/phinx
```

But when I run the command:

```
php vendor/bin/phinx init
```

The output is:

[image]

And after that there is no installed phinx.yml file on my local directory

This is the first time facing a problem while installing a package..Is there any sollutions/suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved the problem by using the command:

```
vendor/bin/phinx init
```

not:

```
php vendor/bin/phinx init
```

Also there is same issue with

```
php vendor/bin/phinx create MyFirstMigration
```

and you need to use that command

[image]

Comment: How you could run vendor/bin/phinx init. It throw me an error "'vendor' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file."

Comment: So my problem is because Windows needs windows separator like vendor\bin\phinx init also without php.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved by :

```
  vendor/bin/phinx init
```

note: withoud the php on the front please also note that for windows you will need to a different syntax:

```
  vendor\bin\phinx init
```